# Get the number of duplicate values in separate columns

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

Im have table

```
+----+-----------+-----------+--------+
| id |   peer    |   whom    | action |
+----+-----------+-----------+--------+
|  1 | 200000001 | 213321213 |      0 |
|  2 | 200000001 | 124321213 |      1 |
|  3 | 200000001 | 124321213 |      1 |
|  4 | 200000001 | 124789123 |      1 |
+----+-----------+-----------+--------+
```

I need to get how many pluses and minuses the user received in total, those should result in the following table
action 0 is minus, action 1 is plus

```
+-----------+------+-------+
|   whom    | plus | minus |
+-----------+------+-------+
| 213321213 |    2 |     1 |
| 124789123 |    1 |     0 |
+-----------+------+-------+
```

Comment: [Sample data](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852/) is better presented as [formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With conditional aggregation:

```
select
  whom,
  sum(action = 1) plus,
  sum(action = 0) minus
from tablename
where peer = ?
group by whom
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want a simple aggregation:

```
select whom, sum(action) as plus, sum(1 - action)  as minus
from t
group by whom;
```

Comment: The minus is supposed to be the count of action columns equal to 0, not a literal 0...

Comment: It's about the only thing OP did mention in the question.

Comment: @Shawn . . . Sorry, that should have been directed to the OP.  The OP may mention that `action` has 0s and 1s but there is no relationship explained regarding the desired results.